# Swift multiple value dictionary

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out how to make a grid of information in Swift. In order to do that, I'm going to need to make a variable that is somewhat like this:

```
var allInformationByDate = [(2016-08-13, 21, 82, 75.75, 38.34),(2016-08-12, 23, 85, 75.25, 38.34),(2016-08-11, 23, 85, 75.25, 38.34)]
```

It's important that I can add dates with their corresponding numbers as days go by, as well as reference a day's numbers by their date.

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to save out other variables (Ints and Doubles) as numbers in this new structure so I can use this information later. I would call it a dictionary, but I think dictionaries only have 2 variables per entry (a word and a definition), but I would need a few more variables recorded per entry. I hope all of this makes sense. Essentially, I'm asking how to build something like the example I gave (or the right way to write it).

Comment: Eventually, I would like to be able to use this information to make a grid or graph of all the information.

Comment: How to build it depends strongly on the source of the data.

Comment: @vadian I would already have these ints and doubles as variables.

var value1 = 12
var value2 = 2.25
etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think dictionaries only have 2 variables per entry (a word and a definition), but I would need a few more variables recorded per entry.

That’s only partly correct. A dictionary maps keys to values. But a value is not limited to one integer. A value can very well be a class instance, a struct instance, an enum instance or a tuple/triple/etc.

So you could simply do:

```
let allInformationByDate = ["2016-08-13": (21, 82, 75.75, 38.34), "2016-08-12": (23, 85, 75.25, 38.34), "2016-08-11": (23, 85, 75.25, 38.34)]
```

But that’s nasty. You should better create a data structure to represent that data:

```
struct DayData { // Let’s guess
    let coffeeInLiters: Int
    let interstateRoute: Int
    let averageBPM: Double
    let temperatureInDegrees: Double
}

var allInformationByDate = [
    "2016-08-13": DayData(coffeeInLiters: 21, interstateRoute: 82, averageBPM: 75.75, temperatureInDegrees: 38.34),
    "2016-08-12": DayData(coffeeInLiters: 23, interstateRoute: 85, averageBPM: 75.25, temperatureInDegrees: 38.34),
    "2016-08-11": DayData(coffeeInLiters: 23, interstateRoute: 85, averageBPM: 75.25, temperatureInDegrees: 38.34)
]
```

Then you can access your data like:

```
allInformationByDate["2016-08-13"]!.averageBPM
```

and you could add data like

```
allInformationByDate["2016-08-14"] = DayData(coffeeInLiters: 25, interstateRoute: 87, averageBPM: 75.15, temperatureInDegrees: 38.34)
```

If you made `coffeeInLiters` a `var`, you could also update that variable, e.g.:

```
allInformationByDate["2016-08-14"]!.coffeeInLiters = 27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of dictionaries and then access them as follows (i have created random keys like value1, value2 and more, you can make what suits you the best and then use them however you want):

```
var allInformationByDate:[[String:AnyObject]] = [["date":"2016-08-13","value1": 21, "value2": 82, "value3": 75.75, "value4":38.34],["date":"2016-08-13","value1": 21, "value2": 82, "value3": 75.75, "value4":38.34],["date":"2016-08-13","value1": 21, "value2": 82, "value3": 75.75, "value4":38.34]]

print(allInformationByDate.first!["date"])
print(allInformationByDate.first!["value1"])
```

Appending more dictionaries to the array:

```
allInformationByDate.append(["date":"2016-08-13","value1": 21, "value2": 82, "value3": 75.75, "value4":38.34])
```

Comment: Thanks @Harsh. Do you know how I would append more dictionaries to that array afterwards?

Comment: On the print lines, it's giving me an error of "Expected Declaration". Any idea why?